# call setNeedsDisplay() inside delegate not work (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UIView class `ControllerWaveForm` and `WaveFormView`

in  `ControllerWaveForm` I have

```
class ControllerWaveForm: UIView{
  var mWaveformView : WaveFormView?
  init(frame: CGRect) {
     playButton = UIButton(frame: playButtonRect)// this button for testing
     playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickPlay), for: .touchUpInside)

     mWaveformView = WaveFormView(frame: rectFrame,deletgate: self)
     addSubview(mWaveformView!)
     addSubview(playButton)
  }
  func clickPlay(){
    mWaveformView?.setNeedsDisplay()
  }
} extension ControllerWaveForm : WaveFormMoveProtocol {
  func waveformDraw() {
     print("mWaveFormProtocol callback ")
     mWaveformView?.setNeedsDisplay()
  }
}
```

and here is my `WaveFormView` class and `WaveFormMoveProtocol` protocol

```
protocol WaveFormMoveProtocol {
     func waveformDraw()
}
class WaveFormView: UIView {
    var mWaveFormProtocol : WaveFormMoveProtocol?
    init(frame: CGRect,deletgate : WaveFormMoveProtocol?) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
         /* I add some CAShapeLayer here 
         */
         if let delegateProtocol = deletgate {
             mWaveFormProtocol = delegateProtocol
        }

    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
         print("call draw(_ rect: CGRect) ")
        if let waveFormProtocol = mWaveFormProtocol {
            print("set callback ")
            waveFormProtocol.waveformDraw()
        }else{
            print("mWaveFormProtocol is nil ")
        }
    }
}
```

when I add ControllerWaveForm to my viewController the console will print :

```
 "call draw(_ rect: CGRect) "
 "set callback"
 "mWaveFormProtocol callback"
```

. but if I click playButton console still print

```
"call draw(_ rect: CGRect) "
"set callback" 
"mWaveFormProtocol callback"
```

it mean the `mWaveformView?.setNeedsDisplay()` can not call `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` inside delegate. So could you please explain to me, thank you so much !!

Comment: Most likely when you call setNeedsDisplay in draw, nothing happens because the needsDisplay flag is cleared after drawing. If it wasn't cleared, then it would lead to infinite calling of draw.

Comment: @ThomasW how can I know when draw(:) finish draw to redraw again?

Comment: Why do you want to draw soon after drawing? Do you want to do animation?

Comment: @ThomasW : No it is not animation? because I trying to create waveForm audio library. When audio playing I need draw current play position in waveform view, so if current audio is 1s, I need compute the position in waveForm view and draw correct line and so when 1s finish draw I will draw  next seconds ( remove 1s line before)

Comment: What you're describing is animation. UI animation, but animation none the less.